# Git issue related to VS 2012 project files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, gitignore, team-explorer-everywhere

I am trying to use git with VS 2012 i have facing some problems. I have not change any file of my .net web application. I just run my application and VS team explorer showing a lot of files to commit. I have added the git ignore and git attribute files as well. So please any one know how to ignore files that appears after run the application(*.dll, *.suo, etc).

Comment: $ cat <path_in_which_you_get_the_files_after_running_app>/.gitignore
# ignore generated html files,
# Add the files that you want to ignore tracking in the .gitignore *.ddl or #*.suo etc
# If you don't want to ignore a particular file use :!filename.ext

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you haven't added .gitignore and .gitattributes via Visual Studio UI. As a result, they do not contain all the stuff Visual Studio usually adds to them (that includes bin, obj, Debug, Release, etc.). Try to remove your .gitignore and .gitattributes. Then, in Visual Studio open your solution. Visual Studio must recognize a Git repository. Then in Team Explorer go to Home > Settings > Repository Settings. In the **Ignore & Attribute Files** section ask Visual Studio to generate .gitignore and .gitattributes. If I'm correct, that should resolve your problem.

**Edit**: if .gitignore was added automatically by Visual Studio, it usually contains stuff like this

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Roslyn cache directories
*.ide/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

#NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding addin-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
## TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your
## web deploy settings but do note that will include unencrypted
## passwords
#*.pubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
packages/*
## TODO: If the tool you use requires repositories.config
## uncomment the next line
#!packages/repositories.config

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since
# NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets.
# This line needs to be after the ignore of the build folder
# (and the packages folder if the line above has been uncommented)
!packages/build/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml
```

Auto-generated .gitattributes:

```
###############################################################################
# Set default behavior to automatically normalize line endings.
###############################################################################
* text=auto

###############################################################################
# Set default behavior for command prompt diff.
#
# This is need for earlier builds of msysgit that does not have it on by
# default for csharp files.
# Note: This is only used by command line
###############################################################################
#*.cs     diff=csharp

###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following 
# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
###############################################################################
#*.sln       merge=binary
#*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary

###############################################################################
# behavior for image files
#
# image files are treated as binary by default.
###############################################################################
#*.jpg   binary
#*.png   binary
#*.gif   binary

###############################################################################
# diff behavior for common document formats
# 
# Convert binary document formats to text before diffing them. This feature
# is only available from the command line. Turn it on by uncommenting the 
# entries below.
###############################################################################
#*.doc   diff=astextplain
#*.DOC   diff=astextplain
#*.docx  diff=astextplain
#*.DOCX  diff=astextplain
#*.dot   diff=astextplain
#*.DOT   diff=astextplain
#*.pdf   diff=astextplain
#*.PDF   diff=astextplain
#*.rtf   diff=astextplain
#*.RTF   diff=astextplain
```

Ensure your files have this information inside. If they don't, copy and paste it.

Comment: @wasipeer, please have a check on replies in this link for the details on scenarios when .gitignore file does not work.

Comment: i have tried but did not find any solution. That`s why I am moved to git bash and tortoise git. These tools are quit handy as compare to VS built-in git option.